# How can an application set its codepage on Windows for "ANSI" functions? Is it possible?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, codepages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change the CP_ACP(0) of windows ANSI apis in an application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033825/how-to-change-the-cp-acp0-of-windows-ansi-apis-in-an-application)

Whenever a Windows program uses "ANSI" versions of Windows API functions (e.g. `MessageBoxA`), a conversion is done according to the current codepage. This can cause many Japanese programs to display their entire user interface as mojibake if the system's language is not set to Japanese.

One solution to this is to use UTF-16 throughout the program, but is it possible to change this codepage through use of the API? How can this be achieved?

Ideally `GetACP` should have a `SetACP` counterpart, but this is not the case.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible (unless I'm misunderstading your question). See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033825/how-to-change-the-cp-acp0-of-windows-ansi-apis-in-an-application) question and [MSDN on Code Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317752\(v=vs.85\).aspx).

Comment: Unless you're forced to update an old program that absolutely can't be converted to Unicode, use Unicode. You'll save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: @user786653, that question was specifically about CP_ACP. You can also use CP_THREAD_ACP but it's not recommended: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/08/22/454360.aspx

Comment: @MarkRansom, I ask this question for a couple of reasons: the first is that it would be nice to be able to encode strings as UTF-8 when writing programs (Windows has a codepage for that), and the second is that it would be easy to modify programs to always run under the correct codepage regardless of how they are invoked.

Comment: Use UTF-16. Don't fight the system.

Comment: This question may be worth revisiting now that [Microsoft is working on adapting the `-A` versions of WinAPI functions to support UTF-8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page).  The linked page is for UWP, but at least some UTF-8 support can also be observed in the Windows API even when not targeting UWP.

Comment: Justin: Lazarus has integrated this approach, and it works. In the Icon/manifest view, you can set a tick to enable this. Another recent one,  long file name support was also implemented.